# Is it possible to make a personal GitHub repo publicly editable?

Tags: github

I've got a personal GitHub repository on a private GitHub Enterprise instance (so no worries about anonymous vandals messing with it). I'd like to make it so that anyone (or at least every member of a specific organization) can freely edit it, while keeping personal ownership of it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for personal repos you are only allowed to directly add individual contributors, not entire organizations or groups.

These settings can be changed within the "Manage Access" tab in the repository settings page.

Organization owners can manage group-based access to individual repos.